# Ceiling light fitting activate by sensor wall switch

Tags: lighting

I have installed a motion sensor in the kitchen, replacing the original light switch. I have a ceiling light fixture, which has six two pin Halogen GU 10 bulbs fitted and I replaced these with six LED bulbs.  They worked fine until after a few minutes when they began to flash rapidly. Is there anything I can add to the light fitting to stop this happening or do I put up with the original Halogen bulbs?  The Halogen bulbs are 40 watts each but the LED ones are only 3 watts each. Thanks!

Comment: What make and model is your motion sensor?

Comment: Try installing *one* halogen and the rest LEDs.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I finally sorted the problem by fitting and AC Suppressor and the supplied Capacitor.  I wired the Capacitor to the terminal block with the two black neutral wires (one at each end) and the AC Suppressor to the terminal block with the black switched live wiring.  The only thing now is that the LED bulbs flash just once around every two minutes.  Not sure what is causing this but I'm glad to put up with it as I am pleased I finally have LED bulbs that come on and go off again via the Motion Sensor!

Answer (score 1):

Not all motion sensors are LED-friendly. More than likely, that's your culprit.

Reinstall the manual switch and see if they work.

Comment: Hi NPM!  I found out that by wiring the AC Suppressor to the Switched live connector (one wire going into each end of the terminal block) and the Capacitor that came with the Sensor unit to the other two black neutral wires (again one to each end of the terminal block) that I finally have a system that works!  I walk into the kitchen, the lights come on, walk out again and after just under a minute, the lights go out.  Just got to sort out (if someone can tell me) the lights flashing just once every two minutes or so! Regards  marsel

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked out for you..

Answer (score 0):

With LED lights any dimmer (possibly the motion sensor) has to be on the load side (the lamp) has to be on the power source side.

Comment: Hi Jason W.  Thanks for you help/advice.  I finally got the lights via the sensor to work by connecting the supplied Capacitor to two of the neutral wires and an AC Suppressor to the Switched live black wire.  All the red wires are linked together.  Seems to be working fine now except for a flash from the LEDs every minute or so.  I ignore it as I'm just glad the light comes on and off again like they are supposed to!   Lol!  Regards  selmar